# Logging Authentication using Applet's SessionID .Secure or Not?

Tags: java, security, applet, sessionid

I am using Applet to Log in to my Web Application where i use the **session id** so as to make it secure for authenticating but i am not sure that whether this is the Correct way to use Applet as My web Application's Platform is highly Secured so i can't risk it.

I am using Applet because i am using Client's Thumb Print Device.

//**JSp Code for call Applet**

```
 <APPLET  CODE="AppletCall.class" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=150 id="AppletECGCapture">
    <PARAM name="jsessionid" value="${pageContext.session.id}"> 
</APPLET>
```

//**code in applet**

```
 String jsessionid = getParameter("jsessionid");
 getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://localhost:8181/ServerSideProcessing/getAppletAuth.html?jsessionid="+jsessionid+"&userName=Ankit"));
```

//**getAppletAuth.html mapping code**

```
@RequestMapping("/getAppletAuth.html")
    public @ResponseBody String getAppletAuth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            System.out.println("DisplayController.getAppletAuth()");
               if(request.getSession().getId().equals(request.getParameter("jsessionid"))){
                System.out.println("Login Done : ");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Login Not Done : ");
            }

            return "appletData";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

So Please help me to know whether i am working in the right direction to make my application Secure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking if it is safe to send a request with a URL like this:

```
"http://localhost:8181/ServerSideProcessing/getAppletAuth.html?jsessionid=" +
       jsessionid + "&userName=Ankit"
```

If you send a request to `localhost` (i.e. a `127.x.x.x` address), the request should go over the loopback newtwork ... and won't go off your computer.  Assuming that your system's local security hasn't been comprised and you can trust the privileged users, the request should be safe enough.

On the other hand, if you were not sending to "localhost", then what you are doing is not safe.  Since you are using HTTP, the connection is going over the network in the clear ... and than some bad guy with access to the network could potentially intercept and read the data.  That includes the start of the HTTP Request message ... which includes that session id.  Once they have gotten hold of the session id, they could (in theory) hijack the session.

The remedy for the latter issue would be to send the request over HTTPS.

---

> ... but i am not sure that whether this is the Correct way to use Applet as My web Application's Platform is highly Secured so i can't risk it.

In that case, you should find a qualified / experienced Java security consultant who *does* understand this stuff completely, and **pay them** to do a thorough security audit of your code.

Asking questions on StackOverflow is NOT an adequate substitute for a security review.

Comment: you are right but i find this 80% secure as `sharvari` has used sessionid which will be generated new every time so will you please explain me where will the problem arise on server?

& Please tell me if SessionID can be duplicated?

Comment: @NaitikShah - I don't understand your questions.

Comment: See `Stephen` from your answer i understood that the Problem will arise only on Server ok.
But i wanted to ask you that why would the problem arise if `sharvari`'s code will generate new sessionid with evry login attempt
understood?

Comment: 1) The code doesn't do that.  2) It would probably cause problems elsewhere if you continually regenerated the session id.  (Like logging the user out!) 3)  One could only tell if it improved security (enough) by examining all of the (real) code, and understanding the context.